# The second cronjob from a file it is not executed

Tags: php, linux, cron

I have a cronjob loaded from a file with ***cron cron.txt***.
The problem is, that the first job runs, but the second does not.
They both run (witout any error) if they are called from the browser. There is no error displayed in error log for the php. 
I tryed to send a mail for myself from that file, but the file it's just not called. The two files download big amount of (raw text) data from a web service's API and load them to a MySQL DB (they almost do the same job, but different data, different database and different schedule).

```
0 3,4,5,6 * * * wget -q -O /dev/null "http://www.domain1.com/serviceArea/crawlDomains/cron.php" > /dev/null 2>&1
0 4,5,6,7,8,9 * * * wget -q -O /dev/null "http://www.domain2.com/serviceArea/crawlDomains/cron.php" > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Any help is welcome.

Comment: One suggestion: Switch first line in cron.txt with the second line to see if you are not calling the second line of the txt. If it is calling correctly then this is not the case.

Comment: I tryed, but it does not works. Thanks for your suggestion anyway.

Comment: When you switch around the lines still the one with the problem didn't work or second line didn't work?

Comment: Yes, the last line is the one with the problem (not the empty line at the end of the file), does not matter which cronjob is there.

Comment: So you should focus on the way you read the cron.txt

Comment: you mean the way I load it? I do with **cron cron.txt**